# SharePoint List calculated field syntax

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula

I am unable to get this SIMPLE calculated field to work. Note that I am not a programmer and do not use codes a lot. So please help in details.

I have a SharePoint list where I want to get a simple calculated field based on 2 column selections (both have multiple choices).

I have a field with region/country choices and one with Roles.

So, if I select CANADA from my [REGION/COUNTRY] field, and then select CCC as a role in the column [Role] I want the result in that calculated field to be "1971".

So, you get that I have multiple possibilities to add in my formula
Can you help on the recipe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [If function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-0a4ad187-dba3-48ae-abe9-bbe3aa6aebca) in such cases which has syntax like:

```
IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

So, for your condition, it will be like:

```
=IF(AND([REGION/COUNTRY] = "CANADA", [Role] = "CCC"), "1971", "")
```

Similarly, you can add multiple nested IF conditions like:

```
=IF(AND([REGION/COUNTRY] = "CANADA", [Role] = "CCC"), "1971", IF(AND([REGION/COUNTRY] = "CANADA", [Role] = "AAA"), "1900", ""))
```

This will result in "1900" if you select "CANADA" in `[REGION/COUNTRY]` & "AAA" in `[Role]` field.

---

Refer below documentations for more information, syntax & available function you can use in calculated columns:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))
2. [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)

---

**Note**:

1. Up to 7 IF functions can be nested as `value_if_true` and `value_if_false` arguments to construct more elaborate tests.
2. Choice field with multiple selections allowed (checkboxes) is not supported to use in calculated column formula.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you could use below formula in the calculated column.

=if(And([region/country]="Canada",[role]="ccc"),1971,if(And([region/country]="China",[role]="bbb"),1972,if(And([region/country]="America",[role]="aaa"),1973,1974)))

Result:
[image]